# reduce/increase the height of slider/seekbar in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, custom-controls

I want to reduce/increase the height of slider/seekbar in xamarin android

[image]

gray is background drawable, green is progress, red is thumb using custom control.

tried to reduce the height of this slider (green and gray part not the blue part) in xamarin android, but not effect. does anyone has any solution for this?

Comment: you'll need to post some code, otherwise it's a shot in the dark